# use socat to provide password to bsign

Tags: bash, socat

I have many servers, where I deploy various binaries. For this purpose I use a script that packs them into archives, publishes to the local repository and then ssh-es to the target servers and installs.

For now I have a script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
packs=(app1 app2 app3 great_app main_server and_so_on)
for pack in ${packs[@]}; do
    cd "$pack"
    svn up
    make redist-package
    SERVER="$(cat ./server)"
    ssh "$SERVER" <<< "wget 'http://dev-server/$pack'; install './$pack'" # ssh uses keys to authenticate
    cd - &>/dev/null
done
```

here, `install` is a special script that unpacks and installs, our hand-made little `emerge`. I removed all error checking to avoid script complication.

The problem now is: I have to sign all the binaries using `bsign`. I want a user to enter a password once and then to pass it to `bsign`. Otherwise it is a pain to enter the same password individually for each of the packages.

Unfortunately, `bsign` has no ability such as `sudo -S` to read passwords from stdin. So… I tried using socat without any luck. I used this line from `socat`'s manual, without result:

```
socat - EXEC:'bsign -si .',pty,setsid,ctty <<< 'My password'
```

`bsign` just shows me the password prompt as if there were no socat. After I enter the password, it works.

My guess is that it's because bsign runs gpg that in turn asks a password. **Is it possible for `socat` to affect that `gpg` as well as `bsign`?**

**Update:** I found `bsign`'s option `-P --passphrase-fd0` which should tell `gpg` to read password from `fd 0` i.e. `stdin`. Will try it tomorrow.

**Update:** Failed, `-P` does not work. It may be caused by a buggy (custom-patched) `bsign` I have to use, though.